# "aborted (disconnected)" on multithreading in python 3.5.2

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I wrote this python code that runs a simple markov chain to generate output, and I want to launch several threads of the same code and have them all report back to one central part of the program. I have assigned a queue to send messages on and one to receive them on, one for each thread I'm launching.  In the main loop of the thread, I put the first item from the moves deque into qIn and I wait for a prompt from qOut to produce another result.  In the main loop of the central part of the program, one of the threads is randomly selected every second and the data it sent is consumed and it is signalled to send more. This all works as intended when running one thread, but as soon as I increase the number of threads, such as 3, after a few seconds I get a message saying "aborted (disconnected)" and execution stops.  What have I done wrong here?

```
import time
from numpy.random import choice
from numpy import array
from collections import OrderedDict, deque
from threading import *
from queue import Queue
import random

class processMarkovChain():
    def __init__(self, qIn, qOut, IOtoCPU=65, IOtoIO=35, CPUtoCPU=75, CPUTtoIO=25, ID=0):

        IOTransitionProbabilities  = OrderedDict( sorted({"CPU":IOtoCPU,  "IO ":IOtoIO  }.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
        CPUTransitionProbabilities = OrderedDict( sorted({"CPU":CPUtoCPU, "IO ":CPUTtoIO}.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))

        self.TP = OrderedDict( sorted({"CPU":CPUTransitionProbabilities,
                                       "IO ":IOTransitionProbabilities}.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))

        self.state = "CPU"
        self.moves = deque(self.generate_move() for _ in range(50))
        self.ID = ID
        self.qIn = qIn
        self.qOut = qOut

    def generate_move(self):
        draw = choice(list(self.TP.keys()), 1, p=array(list(self.TP[self.state].values()))/100)
        self.state = draw[0]
        return draw[0]

    def count(self, state):
        counter = 0
        for s in self.moves:
            if s != state:
                break
            counter += 1
        return counter

    def run_loop(self):
        while(1):
            time.sleep(1)
            retMove = self.moves.popleft()
            print(self.ID, retMove, self.count(retMove))
            self.qIn.put([retMove, self.count(retMove)], timeout=1000)
            self.qOut.get(timeout=1000)
            self.moves.append(self.generate_move())

numThreads = 1
inQueueList = [Queue() for ID in range(numThreads)]
outQueueList = [Queue() for ID in range(numThreads)]
threadList = [Thread(target=processMarkovChain(ID=ID, 
                                               qIn=inQueueList[ID], 
                                               qOut=outQueueList[ID]).run_loop).start() for ID in range(numThreads)]

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    luckyThread = random.randint(0,numThreads-1)
    print(inQueueList[luckyThread].get(timeout=1000))
    outQueueList[luckyThread].put("hello", timeout=1000)
```

Sample output from one thread:

```
0 CPU 1
['CPU', 1]
0 CPU 0
['CPU', 0]
0 IO  1
['IO ', 1]
0 IO  0
['IO ', 0]
0 CPU 2
['CPU', 2]
0 CPU 1
['CPU', 1]
0 CPU 0
['CPU', 0]
0 IO  0
['IO ', 0]
0 CPU 0
['CPU', 0]
0 IO  1
...
```

Sample output from three threads:

```
0 CPU 6
1 IO  0
2 IO  4
['IO ', 4]
['CPU', 6]aborted (disconnected)
```

Comment: I just ran your code for 5 minutes with `numThreads = 3` on Python 3.6.0 on Linux, and it ran fine, with no `aborted (disconnected)` message. What kind of system are you running this on? Are you running it remotely?

Comment: This is being run on a Mac OSX system, does it not play well with the multithreading library?

Comment: I don't use OSX, but `threading` is a pretty fundamental standard module, and it should function correctly on all platforms. It might have some quirks on Windows, but it should behave the same way on all Unix-like systems, including OSX, Linux, and BSD.

Comment: Just confirmed that this works fine on my CentOS 7 host as well, must be the environment.